# Failed to find ledger for channel name "" in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, sap-business-technology-platform

I've been looking for a question like this, but I've not found anything, so sorry if I write something previously written.

I've been developing a smart contract for SAP Hyperledger Fabric in Go, and I've got a problem with the "qscc" chaincode when I try to call it via Swagger API, the code of the chaincode is:

```
func (cc *registroHorario) query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) peer.Response {
    TxId := args[0]
    invokeArgs := ToChaincodeArgs("GetBlockByTxID", "gesjornada", TxId)
    response := stub.InvokeChaincode("qscc", invokeArgs, "gesjornada")
    if response.Status != shim.OK {
        return shim.Error(BytesToString(response.Payload))
    }
    value := response.Payload
    // JSON := Decode("common.Block", value)
    logger.Infof("QueryResult: %s", value)
    return shim.Success(value)
}

//ToChaincodeArgs converts string args to []byte args.
func ToChaincodeArgs(args ...string) [][]byte {
    bargs := make([][]byte, len(args))
    for i, arg := range args {
        bargs[i] = []byte(arg)
    }
    return bargs
}
```

and Swagger code:

```
/{txId}:                            #-------------------------------------------------------- GET /{txId} ==> QUERY
    get:
      tags:
        - Marcaje
      operationId: query
      summary: Listar marcaje por TxId
      parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/txId'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
        400:
          description: Parameter Mismatch
        404:
          description: Not Found
```

When I call the API, I pass my txId as an argument and I've got the following error:

```
500: Error: Internal Server Error
{
  "error": {
    "message": "INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID: 5172ad78a74af6fd0c45af6e7e54f92b03c8e34db1e6387d5d359d27550538fc: failed to find ledger for channel: gesjornada",
    "code": "CustomError",
    "status": 500
  }
}
```

I thought it was a problem of the channel name, but I saw that channel name I got when I call Hyperledger Fabric API via SAP API HUB is that, so I've been stuck here for almost a month, can anyone help me, please?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: That's strange! Have you enabled service discovery on your network?

Comment: Hi @AdityaArora, I don't know how to do that because I'm very new in developing chaincodes with SAP environment.. I've been trying to get where the error came from, but I've got no luck since no much information is posted by them.